# Laptop turned off, now cant turn it on, charger is buzzing when plugged in

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, charger

My laptop just randomly turned off, now it doesnt turn on. I use it without batteries. Now if I plug it in the charger has a weird clicking/buzzing noise. Any idea what happened? I measured the charger and it still gives 19V on the output, so is it something with the laptops power supply parts?

Comment: Are you saying that it works without batteries, or that you were using it without batteries and it has now stopped working.  It sounds like either the charger is poked (likely - especially if its not an original one) and/or the batteries are stuffed and are drawing more current then the charger could put out, causing it to die.

Comment: That's insufficient information. Is the 19V pure DC or cycling on/off? Try a battery or another power supply. You need a 'scope to check the exsiting power supply -- if a capacitor is fried, the DC would be *very* noisy.

Comment: Well the power supply says 19V 4.74A and a straight line and a dotted line each other as a symbol. I dont know what that means. I dont have the batteries with me so I cannot test it, I use it without them usually, is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

I would disconnect the charger and look for a new one. It's been used as the primary power source of your laptop (which it wasn't designed for) for how long? Don't trust it if it has started buzzing, mate. Unplug it and cut the cord in half so that no-one else uses it.